# js module target class

Tags: javascript, jquery, modular

I'm new to modular JS.  I am trying to convert a simple class toggle to a module, but I can't target the correct LI. This toggles all of the arrows.

```
var toggleArrow = {
    init: function(){
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
        //this.render();
    },
    cacheDom: function(){
        this.$el = $('.has-accordion');
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        this.$el.on('show hide',this.toggleAccordion.bind(this));
    },
    toggleAccordion: function(e){           
        this.$el.find('i').toggleClass('page-arrow-down');
    }

};
toggleArrow.init();
// spaguetti code being converted
// $('.collapsible').on("show", ".has-accordion", function(event){
//      $(this).find('i').addClass("page-arrow-down");
//  }); 
//  $('.collapsible').on("hide", ".has-accordion", function(event){
//      $(this).find('i').removeClass("page-arrow-down");
//  });
```

sample html

```
<ul>
<li class="has-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">One<i class="page-arrow-next"></i>
 <ul id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="has-accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Two<i class="page-arrow-next"></i>
 <ul id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such events in jquery on('show hide'), you can add these custom methods.

instead you can just add a class "open" to the opened list, and can change the `<i>` styles with css.

Take a look http://jsbin.com/debuticifo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Might be worth adding some code to your actual answer. If the link goes down this answer isn't worth much.

Comment: The list has Bootstrap's collapsible code attached to it, so it will toggle, and it will register the show/hide methods.  Either way, a click based response works. Thank you!